# Recover prints from Pycharm after computer restart

Tags: python, pycharm

My computer crashed when running a script over night in Pycharm (crash not related to my script). Is there any history saved in Pycharm of prints that happened before the crash so that I don't have to run my script again? If so, how can I retrieve them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't :/ Next time, you should save the results to a file in case if an unexpected shutdown occurs so you'll have the last point before the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible right now, but adding this answer for future references to save Terminal Output as a log automatically in PyCharm.

1. Click on `Add Configurations` from the ***Navigation Bar*** or go to `Menu > Run > Edt Configuration`.

[image: Edit Configuration Option]

2. Open the `Templates > Python >` Then `Logs` tab. Specify paths and options as you want. Read more in [IntelliJ IDEA's Logging documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-log-options.html).

[image]

But the best is to use Python's awesome logging feature. A small example below, [source](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial). This would save anything that outputs in the terminal to a file.

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.INFO)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```